# Isna() function in pandas dataframe returns boolean value but it is converting my dataframe to NaN, why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, nan

I have created a simple dataframe, and then I applied df.isna() method and it's returning true when values are NaN. But when I do df[df.isna()] it is converting my whole dataframe values to NaN, why is that so?

Comment: It is not converting anything. You simply *filter* your dataframe: you obtain the parts where the dataframe is `NaN`.

Comment: No actually I am getting  NaN in all values. [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l73ih52f8u6kRIfpMju1m7fhLcXl3VsF/view?usp=sharing)